# PHP URL Shortening Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, url, url-shortener

Could anyone recommend a preferred algorithm to use for URL shortening? I'm coding using PHP. Initially I thought about writing something that would start at a character such as "a" and iterate through requests, creating records in a database and therefore having to increment the character to b, c, d ... A, B and so on as appropriate.

However it dawned on me that this algorithm could be pretty heavy/clumsy and there could be a better way to do it.

I read around a bit on Google and some people seem to be doing it with base conversion from the database's ID column. This isn't something I'm too familiar with.

Could someone elaborate and explain to me how this would work? A couple of code examples would be great, too.

I obviously don't want a complete solution as I would like to learn by doing it myself, but just an explanation/pseudo-code on how this would work would be excellent.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most shortening services just use a counter that is incremented with every entry and convert the base from 10 to 64.

An implementation in PHP could look like this:

```
function encode($number) {
    return strtr(rtrim(base64_encode(pack('i', $number)), '='), '+/', '-_');
}
function decode($base64) {
    $number = unpack('i', base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($base64, '-_', '+/'), strlen($base64) % 4, '=')));
    return $number[1];
}

$number = mt_rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX);
var_dump(decode(encode($number)) === $number);
```

The `encode` function takes an integer number, converts it into bytes ([`pack`](http://php.net/pack)), encodes it with the Base-64 encoding ([`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode)), trims the trailing padding `=` ([`rtrim`](http://php.net/rtrim)), and replaces the characters `+` and `/` by `-` and `_` respectively ([`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr)). The `decode` function is the inverse function to `encode` and does the exact opposite (except adding trailing padding).

The additional use of `strtr` is to translate the [original Base-64 alphabet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4) to the [URL and filename safe alphabet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5) as `+` and `/` need to be encoded with the Percentage-encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Plenty to get my teeth into now. I shall have a play with Base64. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use base_convert function to do a base convertion from 10 to 36 with the database IDs.

```
<?php
   $id = 315;
   echo base_convert($id, 10, 36), "\n";
?>
```

Or you can reuse some of the ideas presented in the comments on the page bellow:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your PRIMARY KEY is an INT and it auto_increments, the following code will get you going =).

```
<?php

    $inSQL = "INSERT INTO short_urls() VALUES();";
    $inResult = mysql_query($inSQL);
    $databaseID = base_convert(mysql_insert_id(), 10, 36);

    // $databaseID is now your short URL

?>
```

EDIT: Included the base_convert from HGF's answer. I forgot to base_convert in the original post.

Comment: Thanks very much. I can understand that, but surely if you just use the database ID, you are constrained to 0-9 of numbers, so only Base10? Wouldn't it be better to somehow utilise a-zA-Z0-9? Or am I having a very blonde moment...

Answer (score 1):

i used to break ID by algorithm similar with how to convert from decimal to hex, but it will use 62 character instead of 16 character that hex would use.

```
'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'
```

example : if you will change ID = 1234567890 you will get **kv7yl1** as your a key.

Answer (score 1):

I adopted a "light" solution. On user request I generate a unique identifier (checking for conflicts in db) with this python snipplet:

```
url_hash = base64.b64encode(os.urandom(int(math.ceil(0.75*7))))[:6]
```

and store it in db.

Answer (score 1):

The native PHP base_convert() works well for small ranges of numbers, but if you really need to encode large values, consider using something like the implementation provided here which will work to base 64 and beyond if you simply provide more legal characters for the encoding.

http://af-design.com/blog/2010/08/10/working-with-big-integers-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

Here try this method :

```
hash_hmac('joaat', "http://www.example.com/long/url/", "secretkey");
```

It will provide you with hash value fit for a professional url shortener, e.g: '**142ecd53**'

Comment: [As of PHP7.2.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) - Usage of non-cryptographic hash functions (adler32, crc32, crc32b, fnv132, fnv1a32, fnv164, fnv1a64, **joaat**) was disabled.